How can I hide the name of an expression in Grafana visualization
In Grafana, I have created 2 queries: A and B.
And I create an expression calls C which is $A/$B.
Thank I create a Stat visualization, it shows the name of the expression in the Stat panel, like

and 
How I an config Grafana so that it does not display the latter 'C' which is the name of the expression in the Stat panel?
I tried but nothing changes.

